# How to store variable for each user session in MEAN.JS?

Tags: angularjs, express, meanjs

I am using [MEAN.JS](http://meanjs.org/) and I want to store some parameter for each user during his session (from the opening of the website until the closing of the browser without login), and I want this parameter to be accessible from the client side by [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and from the server side in the [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) route handlers.
Please forgive my poor English

Answer (score 0):

Use an express session and set up routes for angular to query:

```js
var express = require('express'),
 logger = require('morgan'),
 bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
 cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
 expressSession = require('express-session');

var app = express();
app.use(logger("tiny"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser('yousecretcode'));
app.use(expressSession({secret: 'yourothersecretcode', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true}));

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/session/set/:value', function(req, res) {
 req.session.mySession = req.params.value;
 res.send('session write success');
});

app.get('/session/get/', function(req, res) {
 if(req.session.mySession)
  res.send('the session value is: ' + req.session.mySession);
 else
  res.send("no session value");
});

app.use('/', router);
var server = app.listen(8097, function() {
 console.log('BASIC SESSION server is listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

Reference: http://blog.arisetyo.com/?p=492

There is an express module called redis that offers a more advanced solution as the aforementioned reference highlights.  Refer to meanjs documentation if you require reference to query the routes or use the Yeoman generator(recommended).

I hope this helps you.